# Do browsers re-try DNS when a page load fails?

Tags: dns, redundancy

After Amazon's failure and reading many articles about what redundant/distributed means in practice, DNS seems to be the weak point. For example, if DNS is set to round-robin among data centers, and one of the data centers fails, it seems that many browsers will have cached that DNS and continue to hit a failed node.

I understand time-to-live (TTL), but of course this may be set to a long time.

So my question is, if a browser does not get a response from an IP, is it smart enough to refresh the DNS in the hope of being routed to another node?

Answer (score 1):

Round-robin DNS is a per-browser thing. [This is how mozilla does it](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/netlib/dns.html):

> A single host name may resolve to multiple ip addresses, each of which is stored in the 
>   host entity returned after a successful lookup. Netlib preserves the order in which the dns 
>   server returns the ip addresses. If at any point during a connection, the ip address 
>   currently in use for a host name fails, netlib will use the next ip address stored in the 
>   host entity. If that one fails, the next is queried, and so on. This progression through 
>   available ip address is accomplished in the NET_FinishConnect() function. Before a url load 
>   is considered complete because it's connection went foul, it's host entity is consulted to 
>   determine whether or not another ip address should be tried for the given host. Once an ip 
>   address fails, it's out, removed from the host entity in the cache. If all ip addresses in 
>   the host entity fail, netlib propegates the "server not responding" error back up the call 
>   chain.

As for Amazon's failure, there was NOTHING wrong with DNS during Amazon's downtime. The DNS servers correctly reported the IP addresses, and the browsers used those IP addresses. The screw-up was on Amazon's side. They re-routed traffic to an overwhelmed cluster. The DNS was dead-on, but the clusters themselves couldn't handle the huge load of traffic.

[Amazon says it best themself](http://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/):

> EC2 provides two very important availability building blocks: Regions and Availability 
>   Zones. By design, Regions are completely separate deployments of our infrastructure. 
>   Regions are completely isolated from each other and provide the highest degree of 
>   independence. Many users utilize multiple EC2 Regions to achieve extremely-high levels of 
>   fault tolerance. However, if you want to move data between Regions, you need to do it via 
>   your applications as we don’t replicate any data between Regions on our users’ behalf.

In other words, "remember all of that high-availability we told you we have? Yeah it's really still up to you." Due to their own bumbling, they took out both the primary AND secondary nodes in the cluster, and there was nothing left to fail over to. And then when they brought it all back, there was a sudden "re-mirroring storm" as the nodes tried to synchronize simultaneously, causing more denial of service. DNS had nothing to do with any of it.